# Validation in Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8, laravel-validation

I´m trying to create a personalized request in Laravel 8.

```
class SendContactFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }
    
    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            'name' => 'required|min:4|max:30',
            'email' => 'required|email',
            'phone' => 'required|numeric|size:11',
            'message' => 'required|min:4|max:400',
        ];
    }
}
```

In my controller i´m using it to send email.

```
public function sendContactForm(SendContactFormRequest $request)
{
    try {
        $data = [
            'name' => $request->get('name'),
            'email' => $request->get('email'),
            'phone' => $request->get('phone'),
            'message' => $request->get('message'),
        ];
        // SEND EMAIL
        $this->sendNotification($data);

        return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->with('success', trans('web.'));

    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return redirect()
            ->back()
            ->with('danger', $e->getMessage());
    }
}
```

But always return `HTTP ERROR 500` i don´t know what I´m doing wrong... I´m watching any tutorials and any code example, but I don´t know what it´s my problem.

**UPDATED**

Finally i did this:

firt i´m creating one `personalised request`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Requests;

use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;


class SendContactFormRequest extends FormRequest
{
    /**
     * Determine if the user is authorized to make this request.
     *
     * @return bool
     */
    public function authorize()
    {
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Get the validation rules that apply to the request.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        
        return [
            'name'    => 'required|string|max:20',
            'email'   => 'required|email|unique:users,email',
            'phone'   => 'required|numeric|min:10',
            'message' => 'required|string|max:400',
        ];
    }
}
```

in my controller i add `use` and create object in function:

```
public function sendContactForm(SendContactFormRequest $request)
    {
        try{

            $data = [
                'name'      => $request->name,
                'email'     => $request->email,
                'phone'     => $request->phone,
                'message'   => $request->message,
            ];
            
            // SEND EMAIL
            $this->sendNotification($data);

            return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->with('success', trans('web.'));
        
        }catch (Exception $e) {
            return redirect()
                ->back()
                ->with('danger', $e->getMessage());
        }
    }
```

now i´m user `$request->variable` before i´m using `$request->get()` i configure my notification and send my email ok.

Now my problem it´s that i tray send my contact form empty, i can´t show messages... But now i can see i my apache log, that i have this:

[

```
Mon May 03 17:55:48.109395 2021] [php:error] [pid 9796:tid 1216] [client ::1:61899] PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 536870912 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 262144 bytes) in C:\\wamp64\\www\\aeveWeb\\vendor\\laravel\\framework\\src\\Illuminate\\Foundation\\Bootstrap\\HandleExceptions.php on line 129, referer: http://aeveweb.local/contact
```

i incremented this value to 512MB in `wampServer` but same result. I think that my code not validate my form, but i don´t understand i don´t know that i´m doin wrong

**update**

function sendNotification

```
/**
     * SEND NOTIFICATION WHEN CONTACT FORM IT´S SEND
     */
    public function sendNotification($data)
    {
        $emailTo = "";
        $details = [
            'name'      => $data["name"],
            'email'     => $data["email"],
            'phone'     => $data["phone"],
            'message'   => $data["message"],
        ];

        Notification::route('mail', $emailTo)->notify(new newMessage($details));
        
       
        return redirect()->back()->with('success', 'Notificación enviada');
    }
```

Comment: A 500 error is a generic error message and covers pretty much every single thing that can go wrong with a PHP script. Check your server error logs to find out the exact error message. For Laravel, also check your logs in `storage/logs`

Comment: @aynber thaks for your response but log its empty for this im here

Comment: You should install and configure x-debug and watch where it breaks.

Comment: If you're not serving with artisan, please check your apache or nginx logs as well. Also, make sure that APP_DEBUG is true. Seem strange that there is no log. It defaults to storage/logs/laravel.log for every instance that I've seen. Have you customized your logging config?

Comment: @FranCerezo thanks for your response. I know in that point my application broken, it´s in validate. i arrive to function validate, but there i don´t know my application breaks

Comment: @JordanCasey thanks for your response, it´s the firts that i showed, but it´s in true... Idon´t understand

Comment: Since we don't have much to go on in regards to the code. Please make sure that you check your namespacing and, if needed, use dd() to debug where the project is dying. Without any logs or more source code, I'm afraid that I can't be of much more help.

Comment: @JordanCasey thaks for your help... I updated my question with one solution for me, i think... but i have any problem still

Comment: @scorpions78 Are you attaching anything to the notification or doing a http request within the notification? It seems to be a recursive loop if you are not attaching large files. Please post your SendNotification function as well for more feedback

Comment: @JordanCasey thanks for your response i attach my second update with my function

Comment: @scorpions78 I see. Please remove your email to avoid spam. Also in your SendContactForm function, within the Catch, place dd($e); so you can see the error. This is why its not being logged. I believe it would be the newMessage class is not included.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i resolve my question with:

```
$data = [
                'name'      => $request->name,
                'email'     => $request->email,
                'phone'     => $request->phone,
                'message'   => $request->message,
            ];

            $validator = Validator::make($data,[
                'name'      => 'required|string|min:3|max:125',
                'email'     => 'required|string|email|max:100',
                'phone'     => 'required|regex:/^([0-9\s\-\+\(\)]*)$/|min:9',
                'message'   => 'required|string|max:400'
            ]);

            if ($validator->fails()) {
                return back()->withErrors($validator);
            }else{
    
                // SEND EMAIL
                $this->sendNotification($data);
    
                return redirect()
                    ->back()
                    ->with('success', trans('web.contact_form_send'));
            }
```